# get maximum rows created within a window of S seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with timestamped rows. I want to get the max number of rows created within some window, say 7 seconds. How can I do that?

I know how to get them within a minute for example:

```
select top 10 
DATEPART(dayofyear, StartStampUtc), 
DATEPART(hour, StartStampUtc), 
DATEPART(minute, StartStampUtc), 
COUNT(*) as a
from mytable 
group by DATEPART(dayofyear, StartStampUtc), DATEPART(hour, StartStampUtc), DATEPART(minute, StartStampUtc)
order by a desc;
```

Here the group by is easy since I can just use DATEPART to collate everything down to the minute level. I could do the same for seconds. But I don't really know what I'd "group by" for an arbitrary window like 7 seconds.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: From a quick search it appears `datapart` is specific to SQL Server, and possibly `top 10` as well, though would be good to confirm.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it with sql-server, that is indeed what I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is rather expensive, but it does what you want:

```
select top (1) with ties t.StartStampUtc,
       (select count(*)
        from mytable t2
        where t2.StartStampUtc >= t.StartStampUtc and
              t2.StartStampUtc < dateadd(second, 7, t.StartStampUtc)
       ) cnt_7seconds
from mytable t 
order by cnt_7seconds desc;
```